# If a giant asteroid were/was heading towards our planet, many people would tell each other that humanity were/was facing an imminent threat. - which?

Tags: tense, conditionals, imaginary-situations

**Example 1**

> If a giant asteroid **were/was** heading towards our planet, many people would tell each other that humanity **were/was** facing an imminent threat.

I know verb should be back-shifted in a hypothetical situation.
However, I am not sure in this hypothetical scenario, should I use "were" or "was"?

Comment: both are possible, were is more formal, in the if clause, but forbidden with singular "humanity".  Please do a check for duplicates, the "if it was/were" has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a conditional sentence of unreal type. (unreal/very very unlikely in the 'if' clause and the main clause). Grammar books call it a conditional type 2.
Being a second type conditional, both were/was can be used. Were is formal.

The formal form uses 'were' instead of 'was'. Here, 'were' is used not to indicate a past time, **but to indicate a distance from reality.**

Other examples: If I were rich, I would go on a world tour. (very very unlikely)

If I were you, I wouldn't do that (non-factual, unreal as I cannot be you).

This distance from reality is used in other constructions as well apart from conditions.

Example: I wish I were rich.